# How to initialize static class member used in template method?

Tags: c++, templates, member, static-members

I want a static constant, `LIST_DELIMITER`, defined in my class below.  However, I can't figure out how to declare it with templates.

```
// MyClass.h
#pragma once
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();

    template<class T>
    void GetAsVectorOfValues(std::vector<T> values)
    {
        boost::split(values, value_, boost::is_any_of(LIST_DELIMITER));
    }

private:
    std::string value_;
    static const std::string LIST_DELIMITER;
};

// MyClass.cpp
std::string MyClass::LIST_DELIMITER = ",";
```

I know there are similar question on stackoverflow but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. One thing that is different in my case is that my whole class is not templated, just the single method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the exact same declaration, including qualifiers:

```
const std::string MyClass::LIST_DELIMITER = ",";
^^^^^
```

There's no template involved in this static class member definition.

Comment: And you don't include `static` because that's not a "qualifier", it's a scope (and linkage).